# Importing a visual studio-project locally on SharePoint

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm kinda new to all this. But I've downloaded a bunch of folders and files from a SVN server. It seems like these are mostly webparts and Visual Studio files/solution for a SharePoint site.

I have installed SharePoint locally on my computer, and i want this SharePoint site with all this features locally as well.

Where do i put all the files/folders so i can open it in SharePoint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Visual Studio Solution you can click on the project within the solutions and set the SiteURL in the properties window to the Site Collection or Server you wish to have the items deployed to.  I would also set Sandboxed Solution to false.  Then right click on the project and Deploy.